# setting up a custom map in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have two tables, data, data_modified in the system i am modifying.  what i need to end up with is a class that looks like this

```
compareClass{
  field1 = data
  field2 = data_modified where id=data.id
```

}

with one class for each record in the data_modified table.

i can do similar with a single query like this

```
select * from data2009.data s, data2009.data_modified m where m."original_data_id" = s."id"
```

but as i said, i would like it to return the above class object instead of the result set that the above query generates.

can someone please point me in the right direction to accomplish this hibernate mapping please

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DTO from the query results using [Transformers](http://relation.to/2133.lace) in hibenate. See [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html) for an examples.

Answer (score 0):

Write and execute a query which returns all the modified data, along with their original data:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select m from ModifiedData m"
                             + " inner join fetch m.originalData");
List<ModifiedData> list = q.list();
```

Then iterate over the returned list, and build a Comparison instance for every result:

```
List<Comparison> result = new ArrayList<Comparison>(list.size());
for (ModifiedData m : list) {
    result.add(new Comparison(m, m.getOriginalData()));
}
```

Note though that since a ModifiedData instance already holds its original Data instance, the Comparison class is not really useful. You could return the list of ModifiedData directly.